# Creating a large frequency table from 'scratch' with specific ratios / values?

Tags: r, statistics, tidyverse

I have a problem that I can't figure out have to solve.
I have 3 (tibble) data-frames with just names of diffrent populations.

**df1** is all, unique, surnames in Sweden and a column with a count.

- 382.492 (unique names * the count) = 10002985 people in df1.
- 10002985 is then the **total population** in the this 'experiment'.

**df2** is a list of all registered lawyers in Sweden.

- 6211 lawyers total in the population.

**df3** is a list of all people with *noble* family surnames in Sweden

- there are 542 unique *names* and 46851 people with noble surnames in the population.

We also know that in the lawyer subgroup there is:

- 106 people lawyer with a noble surname.

Now my problem is that I want to create just **one** df with all this info.
It should look like this:

[image]

**The main idea** is to create a df with one row per population: 10002985  rows.
noble and lawyer is then a dummy variable where 1 = yes, 0 = no. So for example: for the tot_pop, 46851 people should have noble = 1, and 106 out of that group should have lawyer = 1.

Notice that I don't really care *what* the names are - I just care about the ratios.

Notice also that the reason why I want to create a new data-frame without the names is because I think this is the only way to solve the problem, at least the easiest. But if anyone insists -- I can upload some sample data from each df.
In the end I want to run some probability tests.

Let me know if the question confusing. Also, let me know if this is a really dumb way to go about this :p

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION:**

It was quite easy once I realized what I was looking for :)
There is probably a more elegant solution.

```
# pop
pop <- 1:10002985

# noble
n <- c(46851, 9956134)
noble <- rep(1:0, n)

# attorney
a <- c(106,46745, 46745, 9909389)
attorney <- rep(c(1,0,1,0), a)

final_data <- tibble(pop, noble, attorney)
```